# primary key violation issue in oledb destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have created a ssis package that contains one executesal task and a dft. In executesql task i am just truncating destination table data and inside dft i am insert records from oledbsource that is one table in same structure table on 
destination sql server.

while executing this package there is a primary key violation error.Both the tables source and destination having same primary key and i am truncating whole table before insertion.

What i can check in this case.Executesql is truncating data when i executed that without dft and check data in table the table was empty and there is no error won executesql when running witj dft.

please suggest what to check.

Comment: select primaryKey from source group by primarykey having Count(*) >1

Comment: is it possible that primary key having duplicate records in source table that has same primary key as on destination table.

Comment: A table cannot have duplicate values in a primary key. That would violate the definition of what a primary key is.

Comment: data is correct in source but while inserting it is showing primary key violation. i am using fast load mechanism here.

Comment: do you have any other transformations now that you are sure the source is valid

Comment: AFAIR, error will be specified for which record, data integrity is broken. Please post the whole error

Comment: Are you sure that you have a Primary key violation error? Without the error message it's not easy to know. It's maybe another kind of error.. for example: Unique Constraint error, a Not Null error (You try to insert a null value where you can't)

Comment: Is there any trigger on the destination table?

Comment: I removed the primary key and it is running fine.